# How to edit PDF File with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm currently working on a .NET Desktop Application project, I need to manipulate a PDF template by replacing some keywords. It would be great if I can see a simple sample. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

iTextSharp only allows you to modify Form Fields not flattened text.